# Turn csv to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, search

I am new and trying to make a function (get_info) that takes in a csv file and make it searchable.
This is the csv:

```
Country;Capital;Continent;Coastline;Desert;Population[million]
Mongolia;Ulaanbaatar;Asia;no;yes;3
Malawi;Lilongwe;Africa;no;no;18
Gabon;Libreville;Africa;yes;no;2
Japan;Tokyo;Asia;yes;no;126
China;Bejing;Asia;yes;yes;1404
Namibia;Windhoek;Africa;yes;yes;3
```

This should be the outcome of the function.

```
In: get_info('demography.csv', continent='Africa', coastline='no', desert='yes')
Out: ['Mali', 'Lesotho']
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How am i going to turn the csv file searchable?

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
    
def get_info(file,  continent='Africa', coastline='no', desert='yes'):
    result = []
    with open(file) as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[2] == continent and \
               row[3] == coastline and \
                              row[4] == desert:
                result.append(row[0])
    return result
```

Comment: i get this error: IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using pandas for easy access and search queries. The following code is an example based on your dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(<path_to_your_csv_file>, sep=';')

print(df[(df.Continent == 'Africa') & (df.Coastline == 'no')])
```

which prints to

```
   Country   Capital Continent Coastline Desert  Population[million]
1   Malawi  Lilongwe    Africa        no     no                   18
```